# Injeção de Dependências Camadas Application / Domain / Repository

Tags: asp.net, arquitetura-de-software, ddd, injeção-de-dependência, solid

Numa aplicação utilizando os conceitos de DDD estou em dúvidas sobre quem poderia injetar (dependências) numa determinada classe, se existe algum padrão para tal.

É o seguinte, entre as camadas Application, Domain e Repository.

1) Um ClienteAppService(camada Application) que necessita injetar usuario, eu deveveria injetar UsuarioApplicationService e dele chamar UsuarioService(Domain) ou injetar UsuarioService diretamente no ClienteApplicationService?

2) No ClienteService(domain) eu deveria injetar UsuarioService e dele chamar UsuarioRepository ou poderia injetar UsuarioRepository diretamente em ClienteService?

Eu fico preocupado com referência cíclica caso fique injetando classes de mesmo nível.

Mas tbm acho que eu não deveria injetar o Repositório de outra Entidade, pq muitas vezes os métodos do repositório tem uma regra no service que deve ser chamada anteriormente.

Alguém já teve essa dúvida, como vcs normalmente tratam isso?

Comment: Eu trabalho com esses conceitos todos, e posso te ajudar, mas seria interessante se você detalha-se mais a sua pegunta, post as classes do seu exemplo, até mesmo o modulo de injeção se possível.

Answer (score 0):

No início seu texto você questiona "Quem" poderia injetar a dependência em uma classe.

Injeção de dependência é papel da infraestrutura de injeção de dependência.

Em um grafo de dependências 
- "A" depende de "B"
- que por sua vez "B" depende de "C"
- que por sua vez "C" depende de "D"
- que por sua vez "D" depende de "E"
- que por sua vez "E" depende de "F"

Todos esses elementos devem ser injetados pela infraestrutura. Começando ela criação de F, depois E, depois D, C, B e por fim A.

Referência circular é um problema, evitá-la é necessário.

Boundaries Contexts ajudam a limitar essa dependência ao Boundary Context. Você provavelmente não está seguindo esse conceito a respeito de DDD.